# check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '"Array" SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

**NOTE:** This question is according to my last question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48032007/how-to-make-a-new-field-in-table-when-user-clicks-on-a-link?noredirect=1#comment83034918_48032007)

What's wrong with the following SQL syntax?

```
$sql = "ALTER TABLE products ADD ".$supplier_name_ . $p." varchar(500) AFTER supplier_info_1";
```

It is producing the following error:

> **You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '"Array" varchar(500) AFTER supplier_info_1' at line 1**

**UPDATE:**

the `supplier_name_ . $p` comes from this for loop:

```
// supplier info
    $supplier_name_1 = $_POST['supplier_name_1'];
    $supplier_sending_1 = $_POST['supplier_sending_1'];
    $supplier_guarantee_1 = $_POST['supplier_guarantee_1'];
    $supplier_price_1 = $_POST['supplier_price_1'];
    $supplier_colors_1 = $_POST['supplier_colors_1'];
    $supplier_info_1 = array($supplier_name_1, $supplier_sending_1, $supplier_guarantee_1, $supplier_price_1, $supplier_colors_1);
    $proSupply_1 = json_encode($supplier_info_1);

    for($p=2;$p<=5;$p++){
        $supplier_name_ . $p = $_POST['supplier_name_'.$p.''];
        $supplier_sending_ . $p = $_POST['supplier_sending_'.$p.''];
        $supplier_guarantee_ . $p = $_POST['supplier_guarantee_'.$p.''];
        $supplier_price_ . $p = $_POST['supplier_price_'.$p.''];
        $supplier_colors_ . $p = $_POST['supplier_colors_'.$p.''];
        $supplier_info_ . $p = array($supplier_name_ . $p, $supplier_sending_ . $p, $supplier_guarantee_ . $p, $supplier_price_ . $p, $supplier_colors_ . $p);
        $proSupply_ . $p = json_encode($supplier_info_ . $p);

        if(!empty($supplier_name_ . $p)&&(!empty($supplier_sending_ . $p))&&(!empty($supplier_guarantee_ . $p))&&(!empty($supplier_price_ . $p))&&(!empty($supplier_colors_ . $p))){
            $sql = "ALTER TABLE products ADD '.$supplier_name_ . $p.' varchar(500) AFTER supplier_info_1";
            if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE){
                $insert_suppliers = "
                INSERT INTO `products` (`supplier_info_" . $p . "`) 
                VALUES ('$proSupply_" . $p . "')
                ";
                $run_suppliers = mysqli_query($con,$insert_suppliers);
                if(!$run_product){
                    error_reporting(E_ALL);
                    die(mysqli_error($con));
                }
            }else{
                error_reporting(E_ALL);
                die(mysqli_error($con));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: change the double quotes with single quotes at '.$supplier_name_ . $p.'

Comment: @Deep Would you mind please see the UPDATE that I've added. It's according to my last question that you already visited it.

Comment: Try putting single quotes around 'supplier_info_1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here in `MariaDB` ADD COLUMN only applies when the added columns appear last in the table.  For more details about this , please check the manual [link](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/instant-add-column-for-innodb/).

Because in your code you are inserting / creating new column each and every time after "supplier_info_1". This is cause of error.

You should make that column dynamic.

```
if($p == 2){
  $sql = "ALTER TABLE products ADD '.$supplier_name_ . $p.' varchar(500) AFTER supplier_info_1";
} else if($p > 2) {
  $i = $p-1;
  $sql = "ALTER TABLE products ADD '.$supplier_name_ . $p.' varchar(500) AFTER supplier_info_".$i;
 }
```

Comment: Then how to make it dynamic

Comment: I tried it and it returns: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '-1' at line 1`

Comment: Thanks for the answers but another error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''. . "Array".' varchar(500) AFTER supplier_info_-1' at line 1`

Comment: Well, my reputation is that much yet (at least 15 reputation is required!) ... Sorry <3

Comment: My friend, if you like a new challenge about this topic, I posted a new one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48032886/undefined-index-error-message-php).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your syntax

```
$sql = "ALTER TABLE products ADD '.$supplier_name_ . $p.' varchar(500) AFTER supplier_info_1";
```

I see that you use for loop for Add table field in table and use AFTER `supplier_info_1"` in your SQL query.

Once field is inserted AFTER `supplier_info_1"` will changes to updated field.

So the solution is to get last enter field and print it here.

I hope it helps!

Comment: The error still occurs. I also added an UPDATE. Please check it out ... Thanks!