# Undefined index error message php

Tags: javascript, php, sql, for-loop, mysqli

I'm trying to insert some items from a form into my table which is called `products`. The form looks like this:

[image: form]

As you can see I have mentioned out a link which is **Add more suppliers: +** which simply adds a new row to the form. And the script behind that is this:

```
<script>
        $("#addbtn").click(function(){
            var next = parseInt($('#counter').val()) + 1;
            $("#group").append("<table class='table table-hover'><tr><th style='padding-left:10px'>Name of supplier ("+next+")</th><th>Terms of sending</th><th>Guarantee</th><th>Price</th><th>Colors (use , for separation)</th></tr><tr><td style='padding-left:10px'><input name='supplier_name_("+next+")' type='text'></input></td><td><input name='supplier_sending_("+next+")' type='text'></input></td><td><input name='supplier_guarantee_("+next+")' type='text'></input></td><td><input name='supplier_price_("+next+")' type='text'></input></td><td><input name='supplier_colors_("+next+")' type='text'></input></td></tr></table>");
            $('#counter').val(next);
        });
        </script>
```

Now what I want to do is to insert all the values that user has entered in the form to the table in *array*. So in order to that, I coded this:

```
// supplier info
    $supplier_name_1 = $_POST['supplier_name_1'];
    $supplier_sending_1 = $_POST['supplier_sending_1'];
    $supplier_guarantee_1 = $_POST['supplier_guarantee_1'];
    $supplier_price_1 = $_POST['supplier_price_1'];
    $supplier_colors_1 = $_POST['supplier_colors_1'];
    $supplier_info_1 = array($supplier_name_1, $supplier_sending_1, $supplier_guarantee_1, $supplier_price_1, $supplier_colors_1);
    $proSupply_1 = json_encode($supplier_info_1);

    for($p=2;$p<=5;$p++){
        $supplier_name_ . $p = isset($_POST['supplier_name_'.$p.'']); 
        

$supplier_sending_ . $p = isset($_POST['supplier_sending_'.$p.'']);
            $supplier_guarantee_ . $p = isset($_POST['supplier_guarantee_'.$p.'']);
            $supplier_price_ . $p = isset($_POST['supplier_price_'.$p.'']);
            $supplier_colors_ . $p = isset($_POST['supplier_colors_'.$p.'']);
            $supplier_info_ . $p = array($supplier_name_ . $p, $supplier_sending_ . $p, $supplier_guarantee_ . $p, $supplier_price_ . $p, $supplier_colors_ . $p);
            $proSupply_ . $p = json_encode($supplier_info_ . $p);
            $supplier_info_ . $p = array($supplier_name_ . $p, $supplier_sending_ . $p, $supplier_guarantee_ . $p, $supplier_price_ . $p, $supplier_colors_ . $p);
            $proSupply_ . $p = json_encode($supplier_info_ . $p);
            
            if(!empty($supplier_name_ . $p)&&(!empty($supplier_sending_ . $p))&&(!empty($supplier_guarantee_ . $p))&&(!empty($supplier_price_ . $p))&&(!empty($supplier_colors_ . $p))){
                if($p == 2){
                    $sql = "ALTER TABLE products ADD '.$supplier_name_ . $p.' varchar(500) AFTER supplier_info_1";
                }else if($p > 2){
                    $i = $p-1;
                    $sql = "ALTER TABLE products ADD '.$supplier_name_ . $p.' varchar(500) AFTER supplier_info_".$i;
                }
                if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE){
                    $insert_suppliers = "
                    INSERT INTO `products` (`supplier_info_" . $p . "`) 
                    VALUES ('$proSupply_" . $p . "')
                    ";
                    $run_suppliers = mysqli_query($con,$insert_suppliers);
                    if(!$run_product){
                        error_reporting(E_ALL);
                        die(mysqli_error($con));
                    }
                }else{
                    error_reporting(E_ALL);
                    die(mysqli_error($con));
                }
            }
        }
```

What this code does is that it basically gets all the information about the FIRST SUPPLIER and then if the user has clicked the **+** sign, a FOR LOOP starts and gets all the required information

Then if the defined Variables are not empty, it adds a new FIELD to that table. After that, it starts inserting the array to that custom field.

So it looks nice and clean but it returns lots of errors! The 1st error is this:

**Undefined index: supplier_name_2 on line 11**

And the Line 11 goes here:

```
$supplier_name_ . $p = $_POST['supplier_name_'.$p.''];
```

All the other errors are like this one (Undefined Index & Undefined Variable of every input names that I have specified in the For Loop).

So if you have any idea about this, please let me know, cause I really appreciate that. Thanks :)

**UPDATE:**

When I put var_dump($_POST), I get this:

```
    ["supplier_name_1"]=>
  string(10) "supplier 1"
  ["supplier_sending_1"]=>
  string(7) "terms 1"
  ["supplier_guarantee_1"]=>
  string(11) "guarantee 1"
  ["supplier_price_1"]=>
  string(7) "price 1"
  ["supplier_colors_1"]=>
  string(8) "colors 1"
  ["supplier_name_2"]=>
  string(10) "supplier 2"
  ["supplier_sending_2"]=>
  string(7) "terms 2"
  ["supplier_guarantee_2"]=>
  string(11) "guarantee 2"
  ["supplier_price_2"]=>
  string(7) "price 2"
  ["supplier_colors_2"]=>
  string(8) "colors 2"
  ["supplier_name_3"]=>
  string(10) "supplier 3"
  ["supplier_sending_3"]=>
  string(7) "terms 3"
  ["supplier_guarantee_3"]=>
  string(11) "guarantee 3"
  ["supplier_price_3"]=>
  string(7) "price 3"
  ["supplier_colors_3"]=>
  string(8) "colors 3"
  ["counter"]=>
  string(1) "3"
```

And the error that I get now are these:

> Undefined variable: supplier_name_
>
> Undefined variable: supplier_sending_
>
> Undefined variable: supplier_guarantee_
>
> Undefined variable: supplier_price_
>
> Undefined variable: supplier_colors_
>
> etc

Comment: you can use $supplier_name_ . $p = isset($_POST['supplier_name_'.$p.'']);

Comment: where you are getting undefied error in php , just use isset()

Comment: better to use ternary operator , if not undefined then use the value else skip

Comment: @Deep I tried that, but still I'm getting Undefined Variable. Another UPDATE has been submitted to the question. Please check it out. Thanks!

Comment: it means $p does not have the value at that iteration in loop, i.e. loop is not running for $p equals to 4 and 5

Comment: you should get the exact length and use that rather than use $p<=5 directly,  just modify this condition in loop , replace 5 with dynamic number

Comment: What is your actual database structure? I've tried to refactor your code into "less of a headache" but just can't fathom what it is you think you are trying to achieve so I can't offer any suggestions with the exception of totally rewriting your form so you don't have all this _$p disaster going on :)

Answer (score 1):

You have `supplier_name_("+next+")` in the html, but `$_POST['supplier_name_'.$p.'']` in php. It differs the (). `var_dump ($_POST)`; in php and check if your html input names match the POST keynames on the error living lines.

Update:

It seems you're using variable variables.
Instead of

```
$supplier_name_ . $p = isset($_POST['supplier_name_'.$p.'']);
```

try

```
${'supplier_name_' . $p} = isset($_POST['supplier_name_'.$p.'']);
```

or

```
${"supplier_name_$p"} = isset($_POST['supplier_name_'.$p.'']);
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Apply to 'supplier_name_' and others if it works.

Comment: Thanks dude, I did that and I posted the result as UPDATE to my question. Please take a look at it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As per your updated question , I believe that loop is ruuning till $p = 3 But you have used static number 5 for condition.

Because value of $p is empty or you can say those does not exists for  iteration no. 4 and 5 that is why you are getting issue.

you should get the exact length and use that rather than use $p<=5 directly, just modify this condition in loop , replace 5 with dynamic number.

There 5 should be replaced with length variable.

Comment: I have tried multiple times with setting the $p = 3 in the for loop but this problem still remains.

Comment: Please the suggestion in my answer first. Might be you're dealing with multiple issues. Given the errors in your update, $p has nothing to do with it yet.